# Can't run some Python programs after Debian upgrade

Tags: debian, python

I did `apt-get dist-upgrade` yesterday and now I get the following error when I try to run `anki`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import *
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage, QWebView, QWebSettings
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

and this one when I try to run `calibre`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/calibre", line 19, in <module>
    from calibre.gui_launch import calibre
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from calibre.startup import winutil, winutilerror
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/startup.py", line 149, in <module>
    from calibre.utils.icu import title_case, lower as icu_lower, upper as icu_upper
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/utils/icu.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to load icu with error: %s' % err)
RuntimeError: Failed to load icu with error: No module named icu
/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ptempfile.py:27: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'calibre' not found while handling absolute import
  import shutil
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Both errors are mentioned in these [two](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827922) [links](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=826727). The second link mentions needing a Qt5 port of anki.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem with Anki on my machine by installing python-qt4 from Jessie.

1. Go to https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-qt4
2. Download the right package for your architecture (at the bottom of the page)
3. Install it via

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i python-qt4_4.11.2+dfsg-1_<ARCHITECTURE>.deb
   ```
4. Prevent updates of this package

   ```
   echo python-qt4 hold | sudo /usr/bin/dpkg --set-selections
   ```

Comment: That's what I did for Anki, for Calibre I just used the official installer.